# can we change the css styles of jquery widgets and plugins internally with in our page?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can any1 tell me how to change the css style properties internally without changing custom.css file in jquery..so that the internal properties can effect the webpage..like changing properties of widgets and jquery-ui(ex:buttons,datepickers etc)...

Comment: You need to be more specific about the kinds of changes you want to make.  Do you just want to change the styles of existing selectors, or do you want to add your own selectors, or do something completely different?

Comment: yes.i wanted to change the  existing selectors styles like background color and  font size etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the styles defined in the jquery style sheets in your own stylesheets.  CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets.  The Cascading part means that one style can override another.  You just have to place it further down the evaluation chain (or make it more specific, or any number of other ways).

You just create your own style sheet.  Make sure it comes after the jquery-ui stylesheet in your page, and redefine the styles.